# Private Sub cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and trying to work something out. So, I want cell (Ex: D10) on the Sheet1 to auto fill a string (Ex: James) every time I open the workbook. Can anyone help with the code please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • Start with the [Workbook.Open event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) and work out something on your own first. If you get stuck or errors come back and show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code for what you asked for it goes like this

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Sheet1.Cells(10, 4) = "James"

End Sub
```

using this format for specify the cell "Sheet1.Cells(row, column)".
i recommend you to visit the next website for more information https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html